# Não consigo salvar todos os registro do foreach - LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

No id do usuário ele tem 2 registro só que na hora de salvar ele só salva 1 registro e não os 2, como devo fazer para salvar corretamente ?

Segue Código abaixo

Controller Lista os dados do usuário

```
public function listardados(){
    $matricula = Matricula::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();

    //dd($matricula);
    return view('dashboard.renovacao.teste', compact( 'matricula'));
}
```

-- Controller Salva registro do form

```
public function store(RenovacaoRequest $request){


    $user = Auth()->user();

    $dados = $request->all();

    $renovacao = Renovacao::create($dados);


    return view('dashboard.renovacao.confirmacao', compact ('renovacao'));
}
```

-- View form

```
@extends('layouts.app') @section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <form class="form-horizontal " id="regForm" action="{{route('renovacao.store')}}" method="POST">
            <div class="card-panel white">
                <h4 class="center">Solicitar Renovação</h4>
                <div class="row"></div>
                {{ csrf_field()}}
                <right>
                    <a>**Dados Cadastrados**</a>
                </right>
                <div class="row"></div>
                <div class="row"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    @foreach($matricula as $matric)
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s6 m6">
                        <div class="input-field {{$errors->has('user_id') ? 'has-error' : ''}} ">
                            <label for="produto">Nome do Pai:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomerespo[]" value="{{ $matric->nomedopai }}">

                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col s6 m6">
                        <div class="input-field {{$errors->has('user_id') ? 'has-error' : ''}} ">
                            <label for="produto">Nome do Aluno(a):</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomealuno[]" value="{{ $matric->nomealuno }}">    
                        </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
                @endforeach

                <div class = "row">
                    <div class="col s12">

                        <a title="Voltar Para Página Principal" class="btn orange darken-4 btn-info left " href="/admin">Voltar
                            <i class="material-icons left">arrow_back_ios</i>
                        </a>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn orange darken-4 btn-info right">Confirmar
                            <i class="material-icons left">save</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </form>

</div>
```

@endsection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, as tags `input` no seu formulário estão com um nome fixo dentro de um `@foreach` isso faz que ao enviar um formulário com várias entradas apenas uma (de cada nome) seja realmente enviada.

Tente alterar o seguinte:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomerespo" value="{{ $matric->nomedopai }}">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomealuno" value="{{ $matric->nomealuno }}">
```

para:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomerespo[]" value="{{ $matric->nomedopai }}">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomealuno[]" value="{{ $matric->nomealuno }}">
```

Repare que os atributos `name` das tags foram alterados para um `array`, assim todos os campos serão enviados para o seu `Controller`

Caso a relação com `Renovacao` com usuário tenha sido definida e a propriedade `$guarded` ou `$fillable` estejam definidas em `Renovacao` poderá salvar o conteúdo com algo da forma: `$user->renovacoes()->saveMany($dados)` e o Laravel tratará da relação de chaves estrangeiras para você.

## Edit

O laço for do seu formulário ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
@foreach($matricula as $matric)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6 m6">
        <div class="input-field {{$errors->has('user_id') ? 'has-error' : ''}} ">
            <label for="produto">Nome do Pai:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomerespo[]" value="{{ $matric->nomedopai }}">

        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col s6 m6">
        <div class="input-field {{$errors->has('user_id') ? 'has-error' : ''}} ">
            <label for="produto">Nome do Aluno(a):</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomealuno[]" value="{{ $matric->nomealuno  }}">
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
@endforeach
```

O `dd($request->all())` deve retornar o seguinte:

[image: dd($request->all())]

Pelos seus comentários e pelos prints notei que não há relação estabelecida no seu Model User com a `renovacao` que utilizei como exemplo, então não é possível criar com `$user->renovacao()->createMany()` ou qualquer outra operação relacionada a `$user->renovacao()`.

## Edit 2

Para deixar documentado, o array não estava aparecendo no seu `dd`, pois falhava na validação. Como o HTML foi alterado para enviar um array é necessário alterar as regras de validação também:

```
[
   'nomerespo.*' => 'required|string|max:255',
   'nomealuno.*' => 'required|string|max:255',
]
```

Esse código valida a entrada como um array.
Para utilizar o método `create` como você quer é necessário alterar o HTML novamente:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="rematricula[{{ $loop->index}}][nomerespo]" value="{{ $matric->nomedopai }}">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="rematricula[{{ $loop->index}}][nomealuno]" value="{{ $matric->nomealuno }}">
```

Repare que o nome do input foi alterado para rematricula e há mais um nível no array.

Agora no seu Contoller pode fazer algo o tipo:

```
$dados = $request->get('rematricula');

foreach ($dados as $key => $dado) {
    Rematricula::create($dado);
}
```

Sugiro verificar a entrada de dados que o Controller está recebendo e olhar a documentação do Laravel (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#inserts) para entender melhor o código.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86262/discussion-on-answer-by-andre-minoro-fusioka-nao-consigo-salvar-todos-os-registr)

Comment: Só não entendi essa key no foreach, de onde vem ela ?

Comment: <input type="" name="rematricula[{{ $loop->index}}][matricula_id]" value="{{ $matric->id }}"> eu adicionei para vir matricula_id como eu configuro para não aparece no form junto com os demais ?